# Requests not working in Python 3 - only in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using Requests to handle my post requests and ran into a situation where if I run the same exact code in Python 3 I get an invalid response, but if I run it in Python 2 it works!

```
import requests

url = "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/write"

querystring = {"authtoken":"token"}

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"XMLString\"\r\n\r\n\n 
<ZohoCreator>
    <applicationlist> 

... content ...

   </applicationlist>
</ZohoCreator>\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"


headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'Content-Type': "application/xml",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "03197e8c-2aef-4ac4-829d-f7dca06a14be",
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
    }

session = requests.Session()
response = session.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

**Python 3** Response:

```
{"code":2945,"message":"LESS_THAN_MIN_OCCURANCE"}
```

**Python 2** Response:

```
<response><result>
    ... content ...
<status>Success</status></add></form></result></response>
```

I'm positive the request is fine as it works in Postman and this is the code it generated. am I missing something when it comes to Python 3?

Comment: Your `payload` isn't properly quoted

Comment: @wjandrea I tried `"`, `'`, `"""`, and `'''`

Comment: Triple quotes should work, no?

Comment: @wjandrea Nope :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the structure and Content-Type. It now posts successfully with Python 3.

```
payload = "XMLString=<ZohoCreator> ... </ZohoCreator>"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know how it works with python2.
But error show that it happen due to invalid ticket. Refer the link below to generate api and `Post` Url to insert data into zoho creator.

https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/prerequisites/generate-auth-token.html

https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/script/post-url.html#Example

Comment: But why would Python3 result to an invalid ticket and Python2 to a valid response?